# how to get a field that is not part in the Schema in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, web, mongoose

in my database sometimes I need one more field for the document I want to add, I used `{strict: false}`
in my schema like this: 
`const mySchema = mongoose.Schema({name: String, description: String}, { strict: false });` and it works fine with adding, but there is a problem in getting when I want to get a record that has this new value, I cant use this field and it says Undefined, here is an example:

let's say I am making a record like this:

```
myModul.insertMany([{name: 'test', description: 'test description', auto: true}], (error, docs) {});
```

and because of `{ strict: false }` now it has been added

now when I want to get that record I use this:

```
myModul.findOne({name: "test"}, (err, found)=>{
  console.log(found);
  console.log(found.auto);
});
```

the first console.log shows the field in the record, but when I want to log or use that field specifically, it says Undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From mongoose perspective if you want to get a field that is not in the schema you have to do `instance.set` and `instance.get`. Here is one example:

```
let func = async () => {
  let instance = new Model()
  instance.fieldOne = 'abc'
  instance.set('fieldTwo', 'def')
  await instance.save()

  let instance2 = await Model.findOne({_id: instance._id})

  console.log(instance2.fieldOne)
  console.log(instance2.get('fieldTwo'))
  // Has `fieldTwo`
  console.log(instance2.toObject())
}
```

You can checkout more [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5378)

So in your case it will be:

```
myModul.findOne({name: "test"}, (err, found)=>{
  console.log(found);
  console.log(found.get('auto'));
});
```

Comment: you just gave me the information I wanted, thank you so much